# Matching parenthesis

Tags: c++, balanced-delimiters

This is a simple implementation of a parenthesis-matcher. Given an expression, I want to find out if it is balanced.For example, the expression '{{[[()]]}}' is balanced while '{]{{}}]]' is not. I will output a simple 'NO' is the expression is not balanced and 'YES' if it is.

The algorithm is to push every opening parenthesis into a stack and match it against every closing when when pop-ed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include<stack>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

bool contains(std::set<char> & inset, char elem){
  return inset.find(elem) != inset.end();
}

bool charmatch(char a,char b){
  return ((a == '(' && b == ')') ||
          (a == '{' && b == '}') ||
          (a == '[' && b == ']'));
}

void process(std::string inputArg){
  std::vector<char> input(inputArg.begin(), inputArg.end());

  std::set<char> openParen;
  openParen.insert('(');openParen.insert('{');openParen.insert('[');

  std::set<char> closeParen;
  closeParen.insert(')');closeParen.insert('}');closeParen.insert(']');


  std::stack<char> exprStack;
  for (auto i : input){
    char inputChar = i;
    if (contains(openParen, inputChar))
      {
        exprStack.push(inputChar);
        continue;
      }

    else if (exprStack.empty() || !charmatch(exprStack.top(),inputChar)){
      std::cout << "NO" <<std::endl;
      return;
    }

    exprStack.pop();


  }
  if (exprStack.empty())  {std::cout << "YES" << std::endl; return;}
  else {std::cout << "NO" << std::endl; return;}
}


int main()
{
  std::vector<char> input;
  int num;std::string inputString;
  std::cin >> num;
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
      std::cin >> inputString;
        process(inputString);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm practicing Data Structures questions on HackerRank, any suggestions to improve code quality appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go top down:

1. `charmatch` is a bad name for the function. `parenMatch` would make much more sense.
2. Judging by the one range-based for loop, you're using C++11 - so might as well use it to the full extend:

   - You can use range-based for loops directly on a `std::string`. There is no need to copy it into a vector. So the `input` vector can be removed.
   - You can initialize a `std::set` with an initializer list:

     ```
     std::set<char> openParen = { '(', '[', '{' };
     ```
   - Not sure why the range based loop variable is called `i` just to be copied into a loop-local variable called `inputChar`. You might as well name the loop variable that way.

     ```
     for (auto inputChar : inputArg) {
         ....
     ```
3. `closeParen` is never used and can be removed.
4. `exprStack` is not really the best name - `parenStack` would be more appropriate.
5. You should use spaces more consistently. Your indent is off here and there and you often omit a space before the opening brace which doesn't help readability. Also a lot of people prefer 4 spaces indent but YMMV.
6. Use a consistent bracing style. Sometimes you put the opening brace on it's own line and sometimes it's on the previous one and sometimes the entire block is on one line.
7. I'd return a bool from `process` instead of writing directly to `std::out` - let the caller deal with the output concern (Single Responsibility Principle).
8. `input` in `main` is never used and should be removed.
9. You don't have to explicitly `return 0` from `main`.

---

**Update**

Regarding your question of making `charmatch` more efficient: `charmatch` is already pretty efficient - at most 8 compares and 3 ANDs. You could turn it into a switch:

```
bool parenMatch(char left, char right)
{
    switch (left)
    {
        case '(': return right == ')';
        case '[': return right == ']';
        case '{': return right == '}';
    }
    return false;
}
```

However this is a micro-optimization which will probably have close to no effect on the execution speed, in fact I wouldn't be surprised if the generated code is almost the same.

Comment: Is there a way to make charmatch() more efficient? I wanted to use std::pair but was unable to figure out how to. Basically, I wanted to give charmatch an std::pair and it would tell me if it was a valid pair of '(' and ')' OR '{' and '}' OR '[' and ']'

Comment: @creationist: I updated my answer